# I want to load specific stylesheet first in Html before other sylesheets and body loads. How to do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style3.css">
</head>
<body>
All elements
</body>
<script src="js/jsstyle1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jsstyle2.js"></script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Here how can I load style1.css and jsstyle1.js first before other stylesheet and elements in body tag loads ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linked stylesheets will never be loaded before the `<body>` contents. If you want to load some CSS before the body is rendered, you have to put it in a `<style>` tag inside the `<head>`.

Same goes for the script. Plus, in your example, you put the `<script>` tags after the `<body>` tag, which means the browser won't even start loading them until it finished rendering the `<body>`. If you want your script to be immediately parsed and executed, you have to put the actual JS code in a `<script>` element in your HTML markup, again *before* any content inside the `<body>`.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        /* Put contents of css/style1.css here */
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style3.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        /* Put contents of js/jsstyle1.js here */
    </script>
    <script src="js/jsstyle2.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```